# How to save crop video mp4 file into sd card?

Tags: android

How to save crop video mp4 file into sd card? 
I have string which store crop time of video i want to convert this string to byte so i get the video how to do this?

```
commandStr = "ffmpeg -i " + RecordActivity.video_path_save + " -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:" + stm + ":" + 
    start_total_second + " -t 00:" + etm + ":" + end_total_second 
        + " " + path + "/name" + _timeRef + ".mp4";
```

this is string which i get after croping.